# jQuery: If user is logged in, add atr & apply css to element

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I have the following collapsible/accordion checkout form: https://jsfiddle.net/9vjcoLxh/3/

I would like to somehow make the attr and css of the second panel ("Delivery Options") conditional if the user is logged in using jQuery. At this moment, panels 2, 3, and 4 are disabled, and they become gradually accessible as the form is being filled in. You can see the behaviour in the jsfiddle.

The panel with the login form is displayed only if the user is not logged in. If the user is logged in, the panel doesn't show up. This creates a dilemma, because without this panel, the user cannot access the second one ("Delivery Options"). I want the panel to be accessible when the user is logged in so he can navigate through the rest of the form.

I tried something like this (very clumsy, I know, but I haven't had much to do with Javascript/jQuery before):

```
var data = {
    action: 'is_user_logged_in'
};

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if(response == 'yes') {
        jQuery("#panel-billing-heading").attr("href", "#collapse-billing").removeClass("collapsed").css({
           'background-color' : '#fff',
           'color' : '#000',
           'border' : '0px',
           'cursor' : 'pointer'
        })
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-billing").css({
            'display' : 'block'
        })
    } else {
        // user is not logged in, show login form here
    }
});
```

And I added this to my functions.php file:

```
function ajax_check_user_logged_in() {
    echo is_user_logged_in()?'yes':'no';
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_is_user_logged_in', 'ajax_check_user_logged_in');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_is_user_logged_in', 'ajax_check_user_logged_in');
```

How can I get this to work? I'd really appreciate some input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've come up with a solution myself. It's not pretty, but it's doing what I want and works brilliantly.

```
<?php 
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
<script> 
jQuery("#panel-delivery-heading").removeAttr("href").css({
   'backgroundColor' : '#EEE',
   'color' : '#ddd',
   'border' : '1px solid #ddd',
   'cursor' : 'default'
})

      jQuery("#panel-billing-heading").removeAttr("href").css({
   'backgroundColor' : '#EEE',
   'color' : '#ddd',
   'border' : '1px solid #ddd',
   'cursor' : 'default'
})
      jQuery("#checkout-accordion-billing").css({
   'display' : 'none'
})

      jQuery("#panel-payment-heading").removeAttr("href").css({
   'background-color' : '#EEE',
   'color' : '#ddd',
   'border' : '1px solid #ddd',
   'cursor' : 'default'
})
      jQuery("#place_order").prop("disabled", true).css({
   'background-color' : '#f4bbda',
   'color' : '#f9e0ee',
   'cursor' : 'default'
})
      jQuery("#checkout-accordion-payment").css({
   'display' : 'none'
})

      jQuery("#checkout-accordion-delivery").css({
   'display' : 'none'
})


     //after delivery is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-billing').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#panel-billing-heading").attr("href", "#collapse-billing").removeClass("collapsed").css({
   'background-color' : '#fff',
   'color' : '#000',
   'border' : '0px',
   'cursor' : 'pointer'
})
})
      jQuery('#collapse-delivery').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#panel-delivery-heading").attr("href", "#collapse-delivery").removeClass("collapsed").css({
   'background-color' : '#fff',
   'color' : '#000',
   'border' : '0px',
   'cursor' : 'pointer'
})
})

     //after delivery is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-delivery').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-delivery").css({
   'display' : 'block'
})
})

      //after payment is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-payment').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#panel-payment-heading").attr("href", "#collapse-payment").removeClass("collapsed").css({
   'background-color' : '#fff',
   'color' : '#000',
   'border' : '0px',
   'cursor' : 'pointer'
})
      })

     //after delivery is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-payment').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-payment").css({
   'display' : 'block'
})
})

      jQuery('#collapse-billing').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-billing").css({
   'display' : 'block'
})
})

     //after delivery is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-billing').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-billing").css({
   'display' : 'block'
})
})

     //after payment is shown, enable Place Order button
      jQuery('#collapse-payment').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#place_order").prop("disabled", false).css({
   'background-color' : '#F683C2',
   'color' : '#fff',
   'cursor' : 'pointer'
})
      })
</script>
<?php else: ?>
<script>
jQuery("#panel-delivery-heading").removeAttr("href").css({
   'backgroundColor' : '#EEE',
   'color' : '#ddd',
   'border' : '1px solid #ddd',
   'cursor' : 'default'
})

jQuery("#panel-billing-heading").removeClass( "collapsed" );
jQuery("#collapse-billing").addClass( "in" );


      jQuery("#panel-payment-heading").removeAttr("href").css({
   'background-color' : '#EEE',
   'color' : '#ddd',
   'border' : '1px solid #ddd',
   'cursor' : 'default'
})
      jQuery("#place_order").prop("disabled", true).css({
   'background-color' : '#f4bbda',
   'color' : '#f9e0ee',
   'cursor' : 'default'
})
      jQuery("#checkout-accordion-payment").css({
   'display' : 'none'
})

      jQuery("#checkout-accordion-delivery").css({
   'display' : 'none'
})

      jQuery("#panel-billing").css({
   'margin-top' : '10px'
})



      jQuery('#collapse-delivery').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#panel-delivery-heading").attr("href", "#collapse-delivery").removeClass("collapsed").css({
   'background-color' : '#fff',
   'color' : '#000',
   'border' : '0px',
   'cursor' : 'pointer'
})
})

     //after delivery is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-delivery').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-delivery").css({
   'display' : 'block'
})
})

      //after payment is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-payment').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#panel-payment-heading").attr("href", "#collapse-payment").removeClass("collapsed").css({
   'background-color' : '#fff',
   'color' : '#000',
   'border' : '0px',
   'cursor' : 'pointer'
})
      })

     //after delivery is shown, add href
      jQuery('#collapse-payment').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-payment").css({
   'display' : 'block'
})
})

      jQuery('#collapse-billing').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#checkout-accordion-billing").css({
   'display' : 'block'
})
})



     //after payment is shown, enable Place Order button
      jQuery('#collapse-payment').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        jQuery("#place_order").prop("disabled", false).css({
   'background-color' : '#F683C2',
   'color' : '#fff',
   'cursor' : 'pointer'
})
      })

</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

I ended up using a PHP if + else statement. Basically, if not logged in, disable panel #2; if logged in, enable it and toggle the accordion panel. No errors under debug mode.

Hope it helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged in to WordPress, the class "logged-in" is automatically added to the body tag. So you can check for that easily in jQuery. I added an "if" statement around the part of your code that disables #panel-billing-heading:

```
if (! jQuery('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
  jQuery("#panel-billing-heading").removeAttr("href").css({
   'backgroundColor' : '#EEE',
   'color' : '#ddd',
   'border' : '1px solid #ddd',
   'cursor' : 'default'
 })
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working. Anyway, I want the `#panel-billing-heading` element to have these styles instead: `background-color: #fff`, `color: #2d2d2d`, `border: none`, `cursor: pointer`. I think there might be a conflict with the original snippet, which removes the attr. So I could probably use an 'else' statement. How should I update the code?